# A group isomorphism between $\mathbb{Q/Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q/2Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, infinite-groups

> **Question:**  Prove that $\mathbb{(Q/Z, +)}\cong\mathbb{(Q/2Z, +)}$

**My attempt** To prove they are isomorphic I need to define a map from $\mathbb{Q/Z}$ to $\mathbb{Q/2Z}$ which is bijective and preserve the group operation.

On a first sight I thought, $q+\mathbb{Z}\mapsto q+\mathbb{2Z}$ will work. But, it doesn't work (i think). Then I think that, can we use Fundamental theorem of group homomorphism? That is, If we define map $f:\mathbb{Q}→\mathbb{Q/2Z}$ which is homomorphism with kernel $2\mathbb{Z}$ then, it will do the job. But I am stuck here, unable to define such a map.... please help.

Comment: Define the map $\varphi:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}/2\mathbb{Z}$ by $q\mapsto 2q+2\mathbb{Z}$. What is the kernel?

Comment: Why not just $q + \mathbb Z \mapsto 2q +2\mathbb Z$?

Comment: The technical answer @fleablood is that you need to prove your map is well-defined. In this case pretty obvious, but even so.

Comment: @ancientmathematician   " But I am stuck here, unable to define such a map"  I wasn't claiming the OP could take my map for granted.  I was merely suggesting it was an obvious map to try.  To be honest I'm at a bit of a loss as to how that *wouldn't* be the OP's very first thought.

Comment: @fleablood sir, why should be my very first thought would be map $q + \mathbb Z \mapsto 2q +2\mathbb Z$?  Is there is any reason for it?

Comment: Well, we are are mapping from equivalences classes of rattionals of where two rationals are equivalent if they are the same distance in a unit interval to equivalence classes of rationals where two rationals are equivalent if they are the same distance on a 2 unit interval.  As the obvious mapping of a unit interval, $(0,1)$ to a two unit interval $(0,2)$, is to multiply by $2$ that just seemed intuitively obvious to me.  If $q$ is a rational $r$ above an integer then $2q$ is a rational $2r$ about an even integer. Clearly a one to one mapping of classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct bijection is
$$q+\mathbb Z\mapsto2q+2\mathbb Z$$
and your proposal does not work because it has no preimage for (say) $1+2\mathbb Z$.